# Is there a way to submit values not contained in input fields as part of a form in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to modify values in the model used in a form, but I don't want to allow all values to be modified. For example (sudo code)

### Model: User

```
Id : Guid
Name : string
Address : string
Username : string
```

### View

```
<form action="Save">
  <input value=Model.Name />
  <input value=Model.Address />
  <input value=Model.Username />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

From this I want to be able to have the Save method take in a User model as the parameter and contain the Id of the original model, is this possible to do in ASP.NET?

### Controller

```
public IActionResult Save(User model) {
   // Save model changes based on original Id value
   return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of ways to achieve that, being the best ones done in the server side:

Lets asume we have a model like this:

1- You could bind the specific properties you want to be able to change it would look something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}


    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([Bind("Id,Name,Description")] YourModel model)
    {
       //Here only the properties Id, Name and Description would be populated
       //it wont matter if there are any other properties they will be ignored
    }
```

2 - Another way would be to manually choose which properties to change so back to the Model

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(YourModel model)
    {
      YourModel original; //Get it from database!
      original.Name = model.Name;
      //Here save changes and it will only modify the name
    }
```

3 - Another way would be to explicitly tell your ORM if using any that you dont want to change that particular property

On the frontend you can achieve this by disabling those properties, making them readonly but this not a good approach since the user can change it from the inspector.

Comment: Hi Nalnpir, thanks for the answer to this, I completely agree about controlling this from the backend, I think you missunderstand my intention by the question however, my concern is how I get the `YourModel` to populate with the Id of the origional model? Since the values I'm submitting from the Form don't include an Id property?

I guess in the "Edit" method I can pull together the Form results and the model values I have stored?

Comment: `<input asp-for="Model.Id" type="hidden" />` unless the ID is also a route / action parameter.

Comment: That makes sense as an option, it's not a route parameter no, would this not just be adding unnecessary html though? I mean if it's the only solution then no it's not I guess :)

Comment: No, its not adding unnecesary html, like you can perhaps do some custom controller like [HttpGet("/api/v1/edit/{Id}")] so you can have an Id parameter that comes from the url so your action would need to target that. But there is no other way. Take into account that thise approaches need to be verified by the backend since the user can change the hidden value and also the route action